# NavigationLink in SwiftUI bug

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a big problem and I spend hours to find a solution. I will try to be as descriptive as I can be, because there is a lot of code involved and can not post here all. So, to explain my issue, I have a view which have a toolbarItem in the top right corner, a "Cart". After you press on the Cart, there will be 2 or 3 screens where u need to complete information about an order. At the finall step, after i sent the order, "WaitingOrderView" screen will pop up, but there is a bug

So, after the final step, my screen goes crazy. The screen changes from main view to WaitingOrderView without stopping. The application stops responding, and in order to recover, it must be closed and reopened.

```
struct MainView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var syncViewModel : SyncViewModel
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [])
    private var menus : FetchedResults<LocalMenu>


    var body: some View {

        TabView{
            NavigationView{

             MeniuriView()
                    .toolbar {
                        ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                            ToolbarButtons(numberOfProducts: menus.count)
                    }
                        ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                            Text(Texts.mainViewText1)
                                .font(.system(size: 24))
                                .fontWeight(.bold)
                                .padding()
                        }
                }
            }
            .tabItem {
                Text(Texts.mainViewText2)
                Image(systemName: "fork.knife")
            }
            NavigationView {
                AlteleView()
            }
            .tabItem {
                Text(Texts.mainViewText3)
                Image("altele", bundle: Bundle.main)
            }
        }
        .accentColor(Color.tabItemColor)
    }
```

```
struct ToolbarButtons: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var syncViewModel : SyncViewModel
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [])
    private var cartOrder : FetchedResults<CartOrders>
    @State var pushActive : Bool = false
    var numberOfProducts : Int

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Spacer()
            if syncViewModel._order.status == 0 && syncViewModel._order.id == 0{
                NavigationLink(destination: CartView()
                                .toolbar {
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                        Text(Texts.cartText)
                            .font(.system(size: 24))
                            .bold()
                    }
                }
                               , label: {
                    Image("otherIcon")
                        .padding(.top, 5)
                }
                )
            }
            else  if syncViewModel._order.id == cartOrder.first?.id  ?? Int32(syncViewModel._order.id) {
                NavigationLink(isActive: $pushActive) {
                    WaitingOrderView()
                } label: {
                    ZStack(alignment: .topTrailing) {
                        Image("cartIcon")
                            .padding(.top, 5)
                        if numberOfProducts > 0 {
                            Text("\(numberOfProducts)")
                                .font(.caption2).bold()
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                                .frame(width: 15, height: 15)
                                .background(Color.tabItemColor)
                                .cornerRadius(50)
                                .offset(x: 10, y: -8)
                        }
                    }
                }
                .onAppear {
                    pushActive = true
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Watch here the bug]

Comment: Unfortunately, there's not enough here to help debug the issue. The code isn't runnable, because it depends on a bunch of missing types and the screenshots don't give any obvious hint. Is it possible to include a [mre] that people can test out?

Comment: I have faced the same issue. What I was doing wrong was I was changing the value to Boolean in both View and ModelView so that it was changing every time can behaving like this

Comment: @NoorAhmedNatali what value ?

Comment: the one you have used in ViewModel "$pushActive" to navigate further And one more thing use @Binding in ToolBar instead of EnvironmentObject